# apache server only index.html file working all other file are not accessible

Tags: apache, cpanel

We have dedicated server, we move cpanel account from old server to new server.
All sites are working fine on new hosting but one of site which is static is not working.

Only index.html file is working is accessible, all other files (on faulty site ) like images, css, javascript etc gives 404 error. I have checked .htaccess, stop apache rewriting but no effect. It seem all request go to index.html ( only index.html is accessible).

In error logs I get only following error.

> softException in Application.cpp:267: File
>
> Caught race condition abuser. attacker: 513, victim: 0 open file
>   owner: 0, open file: /home/mysite/public_html/images/video-section.png

We have recreated site by removing account from cpanel, but facing same issue.

Comment: Looks like your permissions are all messed up

Comment: I have give all permission 664, 775 and even 777 to public_html folder but no luck